# Printing output in Table with alternate row colors in PHP

Tags: php

So my code is below.The for loop is concatenating the elements from 2 arrays and printing them in a table.

I have 2 questions:

1) Although the output is correct I would like to print the output by calling the first function (fullname) in the second function (printTable).
2) I would like to print the output that is in the table rows in alternate colors of red and green.

```
<?php

$firstname=
array("Raj","Swati","Kunal","Hema","Kareena","Deepika","Shilpa","Amitabh","Shahrukh","Kangana"); 

$lastname=
array("Kumar","Sharma","Kapoor","Malini","Kapoor","Padukone","Shetty","Amitabh","Shahrukh","Kangana");


function fullname($fname,$lname){

for ($i=0; $i <10; $i++) {
    $wholename[]=$fname[$i]." ".$lname[$i];
}
return $wholename;
}

function printTable($firstname,$lastname){

echo"<table border='1'>";
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
echo"<tr><td>".$firstname[i]." ".$lastname[i]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
printTable($firstname,$lastname);
?>
```

Comment: You mean odd and even colors in the table? You can solve that with basic CSS.

Comment: yes, but If I am putting the loop in a table how do I differentiate one row from the next.

Comment: css pseudo selector `tr:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(even)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use CSS for alternating row colours, you can use the remainder/mod operator `%` on the loop variable.  `$i % 2` means the remainder when `$i` is divided by 2 (ie, alternating 0,1,0,1,... as `$i` is incremented).

```
if (($i % 2) == 0) {echo "<tr bgcolor=#ff0000>"} else {echo "<tr bgcolor=#00ff00>"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<?php
    $firstname=
    array("Raj","Swati","Kunal","Hema","Kareena","Deepika","Shilpa","Amitabh","Shahrukh","Kangana"); 

    $lastname=
    array("Kumar","Sharma","Kapoor","Malini","Kapoor","Padukone","Shetty","Amitabh","Shahrukh","Kangana");


    function fullname($index){
        return $firstname[$index] . " " . $lastname[$index];
    }

    function printTable(){
        echo"<table border='1'>";
        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
            echo"<tr><td>".fullname($i)."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    printTable();
?>
```

For the row colouring see: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd

Comment: function full name is interesting. I did not know you could use an argument without declaring that variable first. And in this context what does the return keyword do ?

Comment: You defined `$firstname` and `$lastname` globally in the script. This is why they are available in the function fullname() it returns a string with the first and last names of the given index, so if `$index = 1` it will return `"Swati Sharma"` you loop in the printTable function so there should be no need to loop a seccond time. If you don't define `$firstname` and `$lastname` globally you should pass them.